# How to access a XFS partition on external USB drives?

Tags: permissions, xfs

How do I obtain access rights in XFS?

My external HD connected to a Samsung SmartTV keeps on breaking down. I want to add avi and mk4 files to the hard-drive but I have no access via Ubuntu. How should I try to get access to a USB drive formatted with XFS?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when a storage unit (partition, drive, etc.) is formatted, the owner of the space is root. Try changing the devices permissions. Make your user account the owner and allow all users full access to the storage unit.